# How to simply update an SQL table in a database using Hangfire? ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, hangfire

I want to simply update a table using hangfire?

The documentation for hang fire is very limited. I was able to connect my database to hangfire as I was able to view the dashboard.

I could not work out how to do it myself. Any contribution would be great.

Comment: The documentation is OK. This question though is very vague. What do you mean "simply update a SQL table"? Hangfire will execute the the functions you provide. *Have* you written such a function? What does the *dashboard* have to do with your custom function? Are you asking how to configure Hangfire perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

First create a startup file  as below :

```
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.Dashboard;
using Hangfire.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using MvcSample;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Startup))]

namespace MvcSample
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .UseSqlServerStorage(@"Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=Hangfire.Sample;Trusted_Connection=True;")
                .UseMsmqQueues(@".\Private$\hangfire{0}", "default", "critical")
                .UseDashboardMetric(SqlServerStorage.ActiveConnections)
                .UseDashboardMetric(SqlServerStorage.TotalConnections)
                .UseDashboardMetric(DashboardMetrics.FailedCount);

            app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        }
    }
}
```

and after that 
You just have to call your function in place of Myfucntion in the below example

```
var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(
    () => MyFunction());
```